# What is the Plutonian equivalent of geocentric?

Tags: adjectives, greek, derivational-morphology

A satellite going around the earth is in *geocentric* orbit.

The Earth is in a *heliocentric* orbit about the sun.

Something going around Mars is *areocentric*.

What about the moons of Pluto? *Pluto-centric*?

---

References used for research:

- Wikipedia’s [List of Orbits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_orbits) page
- Johns Hopkins Propulsion Laboratory’s [New Horizons](http://pluto.jhuapl.edu/) website

Comment: Ask an [astronomer](http://space.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Downvoted. The question could be answered with a Google search.

Comment: @Tim Romano Using, google, and other books, I had found phrases like "Pluto-centric", "Mars-Centric", "Venus-centric", "Moon-centric".  I found that "areocentric" has been used for some time instead of "Mars-Centric" and "selenocentric" in lieu of "Moon-centric".  Yet not the equivalent for Pluto.

Comment: [The geometry during NH observations of Pluto 10 days before closest approach is depicted, showing the subspacecraft and subsolar points, and the day-night terminator, in a **plutocentric** frame.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+plutocentric+frame%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). The term can easily be derived by standard production rules for English, even if it's not likely to be found in any dictionary (or used very often).

Comment: There estimated to be – how many stars? I've not come across 'S-Doradus-centric', 'Alpha-Centauri-centric',  'ULAS J0015+01-centric', or 'PSR1257 + 12 B-centric'. And I wouldn't want to.  Workarounds are preferable. Productivity 'rules' have their limitations. That having been said, is 'Pluto-centric' in any dictionary?

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Agree. English does not need a -centric for every object in space.  Yet with common applications, unique terms do arise.  With the recent interest in Pluto, thought there might me something special other than the constructed "Pluto-centric?".

Comment: Do not understand @HotLicks and TimRomano responses. Seems like a perfectly valid question. Upvoted.

Comment: @Jedidja - The point is that this is a question about astronomy, not English.

Comment: @HotLicks according to http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, applicable questions include "Word choice and usage". Wouldn't that apply here?

Comment: @chux:  so you're hoping for a *recondite* term, not the one that is readily found by Googling because it is currently in wide use?

Comment: @Tim Romano 1 I am looking for a potential proper term, should it not be "pluto-centric".  In the past, a word like geocentric sounded to me like a proper generic "orbiting a planet", any planet, adjective.  Later I  learned more in read articles using: "areocentric" (Mars),  "selenocentric" (Moon), and discussing "'Jovian moons" (Jupiter). Perhaps there exists a term for Pluto-like.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## *Hadeocentric*

As Earth to Gaea gives *geocentric* and Jupiter as Jove gives *jovicentric*,
so too does Pluto to Hades give [***hadeocentric***](https://eunoiareview.wordpress.com/2013/05/26/my-soul-delivers-an-elegy-for-me/).

*Hades* was the Greek god of the underworld, the Roman Pluto.

The word ***hadeocentric*** is based on the pattern of choosing Greek prefixes for words like *heliocentric, geocentric, areocentric* — which, for whatever reason, have won out over **suncentric, *earthcentric, *marscentric*.

#### A Plutarch’s Lives

The problem with using *pluto-* as a combining form here is that “plutocentric” **already means something**, and it means something else altogether different from any astronomical sense: it instead carries economic or political overtones.

Roping the existing *plutocentric*<sup>1</sup> into an alternate orbital sense thus risks being misunderstood as meaning something related to *plutocracy, plutocrats, plutarchy* — that is, to a money-centered form government or those who support it.

Whereas with ***hadeocentric***, no such possible confusion can arise.

---

### <sub>Footnotes</sub>

Citations for *plutocentric* used in the money-loving sense include:

- But Bombay, with its **plutocentric** values, its pavement sleepers, its brutal mafia, did something to people, something violent and un-Indian. 
  —*The revised Kama sutra: a novel of colonialism and desire, with arbitrary footnotes and a whimsical glossay*, Richard Crasta.
- It is only through a **plutocentric** and consumerist culture that we have come to equate wealth with money, though no doubt resources can play a role in well-being. 
  —*Cultivating Reality: How the Soil Might Save Us*,  Ragan Sutterfield.
- Once the **plutocentric** constraints are lifted, however, it is
  plausible to assume that the satisfaction of curiosity becomes a goal from
  time to time. In other parts of the *Republic*, Plato is happy to allow characters who rank well below the philosopher to pursue some form of intellectual interest. 
  —*Plato’s Critique of the Democratic Character*, Dominic Scott.
- Modern civilization is governed by a hybristic ***plutocentric*** culture, addicted to and trafficking in wealth at such a monstrous scale that its whole human and ideological Flatland of modern order tolerates no subversive or heretic contrarian formulations of belief or valuation. 
  —*The Comics Journal*, Issues 262-264, 2004.

Comment: Except that Gaea and Jupiter are personal names, and Hades is a place.

Comment: @AndrewLeach [Hades (/ˈheɪdiːz/; from Ancient Greek Ἅιδης/ᾍδης) was the ancient Greek god of the underworld. Eventually, the god's name came to designate the abode of the dead.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hades)

Comment: Well well. I must have known that at some point (did quite a bit of Greek mythology at school) and forgotten it. The shame. But there's no reason not to use the personal name *Pluto* and *plutocentric,* surely.

Comment: @AndrewLeach If it were up to me, I’d also go with suncentric, earthcentric, mooncentric, marscentric. But for some reason, we don’t.

Comment: One of the 7 hits for _hadeocentric_ I find reads: 'A little Hadeocentric aka Pluto centric astronomy'. There are almost 4 000 (doubtless not all relevant) hits for _plutocentric_. This is the specious 'argument by analogy' /  'mass productivity' .

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Plutocrats naturally prefer plutocentric forms of government.

Comment: But they seem to fail to planet properly.

Comment: Hey, youse guys at NASA and JPL: when you say "Pluto-centric", do you mean "money-loving" or "circling around the (dwarf) planet  Pluto"?  We are easily led astray by any ambiguity here on ELU.

Comment: The pattern of combining Greek terms for the heavenly bodies with *-centric* creates a curious kind of Greek-Roman-Greek sandwich, like a slice of  *prosciutto* between two of ψωμί: for *centrum* is Latin, but -ικ- is Greek.

Comment: Pluto "(god of) riches, i.e. minerals", was Greek before it was Latin, as a euphemism for Hades. Like Plato > Plato-n-ic, Pluto has an -n- stem (and Greek does not delete the final -n in the nominative); so a formation following the rules of Greek would be _plutonocentric_ (_Plouton, Ploutonos_). And @TRomano, that's how you would disambiguate it from "money-loving". :-)

Comment: @Nick Nicholas:  That's how a classicist would disambiguate here. *Hoi polloi* must rely upon context.